# Definition of Infinity

Tags: set-theory

I stumbled over the following "definition" or "theorem":

> A set $X$ is infinit iff there is a injective map from $X$ to a subset $Y\subsetneq X$.

So i tried proofing the statement:

$"\Longleftarrow":$

Is clear

$"\Longrightarrow":$

Here I think one needs the well-ordering theorem:

Take the well-ordered infinit set $(X,<)$ and the map:

$$\phi: X\longrightarrow X\setminus\lbrace x_{\text{min}}\rbrace:y\mapsto \sup_< \lbrace z \in X: y<z\rbrace$$

which is injective.

Is there a way to proof the statement without using the well-ordering principal or brothers? (Is my idea correct?)

Comment: That looks like a definition to me, rather than a theorem, thus there is nothing to prove...

Comment: @XanderHenderson and OP: The standard definition of infinite is not finite, under a weak form of choice these can be proven to be equivalent, using well ordering is intuitive but is massive overkill.Also I’m pretty sure this question has been asked before many times.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition is the definition of a [Dedekind infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set). It is well-known that it is independent of ZF (without the axiom of choice) whether all infinite sets are Dedekind infinite, but countable choice is enough to prove the equivalence.